# При создание документа в формате .odt с использованием QTextDocumentWriter нет таблицы на выходе

Tags: qt, qt5.15

Хочу получить на выходе файл формата .odt для либрыОфиса.
В файле должны быть таблицы, текст, картинки. Начал с таблиц.
Сделал тестовый код:

```
    ui->textEdit->setHtml(QString(
                              "<style>"
                               //для всех таблиц
                              //"table {width:100%;background: black;border: 2px solid white;}"
                              //"th { padding: 3px; color:white; background-color: black;border: 1px solid white;border-collapse:collapse;}"
                              //"tr { padding: 3px;color:white; background-color: black;border: 1px solid white;border-collapse:collapse;}"
                              //"td { padding: 3px;color:white; background-color: black;border: 1px solid white;border-collapse:collapse;}"

                               //класс на каждую ячейку
                               ".outer {background-color: cyan;}"
                               ".inner {padding: 1px; background-color: black;}"
                               ".cell_A { padding: 3px; color:black; background-color: white;}"
                               ".cell_B { padding: 3px; color:white; background-color: gray;}"
                              "</style> "

                            "<H1><CENTER>"
                            "<font color='black'><b>ПРОТОКОЛ ИСПЫТАНИЯ АККУМУЛЯТОРА №1</b>"
                            "</CENTER></H1>"

                            " <CENTER> "
                            " <TABLE class='outer'>"
                            " <tr>"

                            " <td>"
                            " <TABLE class='inner'>"
                            " <tr class='cell_A'><td class='cell_A'>Емкость при разряде</td><td class='cell_A'>43</td></tr>"
                            " <tr class='cell_A'><td class='cell_A'>Остаточная емкость</td><td class='cell_A'>86</td></tr>"
                            " <tr class='cell_A'><td class='cell_A'>Энергия полная</td><td class='cell_A'>556</td></tr>"
                            " <tr class='cell_A'><td class='cell_A'>Емкость при заряде</td><td class='cell_A'>52</td></tr>"
                            " <tr class='cell_A'><td class='cell_A'>КПД заряда</td><td class='cell_A'>83</td></tr>"
                            " </TABLE> "
                            " </td>"

                            " <td>"
                            " <TABLE class='inner'>"
                            " <tr class='cell_B'><td class='cell_B'>ЭПС 90% разряд</td><td class='cell_B'>11</td></tr>"
                            " <tr class='cell_B'><td class='cell_B'>ЭПС 50% разряд</td><td class='cell_B'>12</td></tr>"
                            " <tr class='cell_B'><td class='cell_B'>ЭПС 90% заряд</td><td class='cell_B'>13</td></tr>"
                            " <tr class='cell_B'><td class='cell_B'>ЭПС 50% заряд</td><td class='cell_B'>11</td></tr>"
                            " <tr class='cell_B'><td class='cell_B'></td><td class='cell_B'>4</td></tr>"
                            " </TABLE> "
                            " </td>"

                            " </tr>"
                            " </TABLE> "
                            " </CENTER>"
                               ));

     textDocument =  ui->textEdit->document(); // создаем документ
     QTextDocumentWriter writer; // импорт документа в .odt формат
     writer.setFormat("odf");
     writer.setFileName("/media/usb0/report.odt");
     writer.write(textDocument);
```

Но в выходном файле отсутствует таблица. В QTextEdit есть таблица, проверил выводом на экран.

[image: Что выдал editor]

[image: что получил]

Comment: В документации по `QTextEdit` в разделе `Supported HTML Subset ` ничего не написано про поддержку атрибута `class` у тэга `TABLE`. Я убрал их и получил документ с таблицей.

Comment: А почему при выводе на экран таблица отображается в QTextEdit?

Comment: Значит отобразить может, а в `QTextDocument` перевести не может:
Qt's text widgets are able to display rich text, specified using a subset of HTML 4 markup. Widgets that use QTextDocument, such as QLabel and QTextEdit, are able to display rich text specified in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В документации по `QTextEdit` в разделе "Supported HTML Subset" ничего не написано про поддержку атрибута `class` у тэга `TABLE`. Я убрал его и получил документ с таблицей.
Тот факт, что это работает при отображении, еще не означает, что этот атрибут может быть портирован в `odt`. Философия `Qt` гласит примерно так - если какая-то недокументированная опция где-то работает, нет гарантии, что она будет работать везде.

Comment: А вложенные таблицы документированы но они не работают.

Comment: @zhilenkov, Я не нашел в документации про вложенные таблицы.